# UWP SQLite query result class contains another class

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, sqlite-net

I know that we can do a multiple tables query, like this:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
{
    var result = db.Query<PersonWithAddress>(
        @"SELECT Person.Id, Person.Name, Person.Surname, 
            Address.Street, Address.City, Address.Country
        FROM Person INNER JOIN Address ON Person.AddressId = Address.Id;");
}

private class PersonWithAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

*Reference from [Query multiple tables SQLite Windows 10 UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850610/query-multiple-tables-sqlite-windows-10-uwp)

But how about I need the result class **PersonWithAddress** should be :

```
private class PersonWithAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Address mAddress { get; set}
}

private class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for a way of DataReader, but it's seem SQLite on UWP doesn't support it.

Comment: The linked question also mentions SQLite-Net.Extensions. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/) that provides method resembles the DataReader.

To use this library, we can install it form [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/) and then use it like following:

```
List<PersonWithAddress> PersonWithAddressList = new List<PersonWithAddress>();

using (var connection = new SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
{
    using (var statement = connection.Prepare(@"SELECT Person.Id, Person.Name, Person.Surname, Address.Street, Address.City, Address.Country FROM Person INNER JOIN Address ON Person.AddressId = Address.Id;"))
    {
        while (statement.Step() == SQLitePCL.SQLiteResult.ROW)
        {
            var personWithAddress = new PersonWithAddress();
            personWithAddress.Id = Convert.ToInt32(statement[0]);
            personWithAddress.Name = (string)statement[1];
            personWithAddress.Surname = (string)statement[2];
            personWithAddress.mAddress.Street = (string)statement[3];
            personWithAddress.mAddress.City = (string)statement[4];
            personWithAddress.mAddress.Country = (string)statement[5];

            PersonWithAddressList.Add(personWithAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this blog: [The new Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/the-new-portable-class-library-for-sqlite/).

Another way for multiple tables query is using [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), you can specify the relationships in the entities. For example, in your project, add a reference to [SQLiteNetExtensions NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/). Also available with Async support in [SQLiteNetExtensions.Async NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/). Then change your class like following:

```
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Address))]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Address mAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

After this, we can use following code to get all persons with address:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
{
    List<Person> PersonsWithAddress = connection.GetAllWithChildren<Person>();
}
```